# Huge memory increase when using Auto layout in WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've discovered a strange problem with one of my layouts. When using a `Grid` `RowDefinition` with `Height=Auto`, the application takes much longer to startup and consumes 5x as much memory. I've managed to create a sample application to demonstrate:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MemoryHog.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mh="clr-namespace:MemoryHog"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <mh:DataSource x:Key="DataSource"/> <!-- 15000 strings-->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- "Auto" = 112mb, "22" = 22mb. Auto takes much longer to startup -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" DataContext="{StaticResource DataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
        <StatusBar Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**DataSource.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MemoryHog
{
    class DataSource
    {
        public DataSource()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 15000; ++i)
            {
                this.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}", i + 1));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<String> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Look at my comment in MainWindow.xaml, if you set the `RowDefinition.Height` to `Auto` the app will consume 112MB of memory, but if you change it to be `22`, the app will only consume 22MB! What is going on here? Is this a bug?

---

**Edit** The memory increase is directly proportional to the number of items in the `ListView`, and the memory stays allocated forever.

Comment: Probably that is the feature of WPF, not bug.
If that memory goes away with time, that's okay.

Comment: What happens if you put the StatusBar above the ListView in the XAML?  You have a lot of data being loaded (which you should probably try to Virtualize if possible, but that's a separate issue), so you're likely triggering a lot of measure/arrange passes as the visual tree gets updated.  The order of the child elements in the Grid might possibly have an impact on how this calculation gets performed, but in general it's always going to be more complicated when more than one column has automatic or proportional sizing.

Comment: @JackMalkovich No, the memory usage doesn't drop over time!

Comment: @DanBryant The order in the XAML makes no difference. Virtualization helps a little with the memory usage, but it's still higher than it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `RowDefinition.Height` to `Auto` effectively breaks UI virtualization, by putting your 15000 rows-long `ListView` in an "infinite container" where it gets as much vertical size as it wants, and is not restricted by anything. This means that all 15000 `ListViewItem`s are effectively created (unnecessarily, because they're not displayed on screen due to screen size restrictions).

Use a `DockPanel` or leave the Height untouched: `<RowDefinition/>`.

Comment: Note that the ListView is actually in the '*' row rather than the 'Auto' row.